# LINQPad SQLite numeric value cast

Tags: sqlite, linqpad

A table in sqlite file has a INTEGER column and a REAL column.
When I use LinqPad IQ driver to connect to this file, the data context is made with a Int32? field and a Single? field.
But the real data in the sqlite table are Int64? and double?, so InvalidCastException are thrown when I try to query the data.

Is there a way I can work around this problem?

Comment: Don't see that behaviour with the 2.0.7.0 drivers. I can query data, but I get wrong values if they don't fit (eg 2147483648 displays as -2147483648).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with SQLite is that the column types are just a suggestion. In other words, users can put anything they like into any column, regardless of its type. This plays havoc with ORMs or queries that rely on static typing.